# Center ul content using bootstrap or css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a ul nav which I've tried to center using `text-center` and failed. Also tried using `margin-auto` which also failed. I need to have the li centered equally. Possibly could use `grid` if it's turns out to be more elegant.

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-side-padding text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills movie-sel-ul text-center">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Now Showing</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">By Theatre</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Buy Tickets/Passes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825184/how-to-center-nav-bar-pills

Answer (score 3):

Just add `inline-block` to `ul`

**CSS**

```
ul{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-side-padding text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills movie-sel-ul text-center">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Now Showing</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">By Theatre</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Buy Tickets/Passes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/270/)**

Comment: This means that if he adds another ul after that they will be on the same line, I think it would be better to make the ul display: block; and make the li's inline-block instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the li to be `inline-block` that allows them to be centered:

```css
ul {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 no-side-padding text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills movie-sel-ul text-center">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Now Showing</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">By Theatre</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Buy Tickets/Passes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

(the padding is just to make it look a bit better, adjust that as you like)

```
ul {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWBJOd

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
ul.nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

to your css:

```css
ul.nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-12 no-side-padding text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills movie-sel-ul text-center">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Now Showing</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">By Theatre</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Buy Tickets/Passes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```